# Imagemagick svg to jpg removes space when using åäö

Tags: svg, imagemagick, jpeg

I'm using imagemagick to convert svg files to jpg/png on server. Painly it doesn't render the jpg-image correct.

The problem occurs when I use åäö as first letter in the second word. Then it removes the space between the words. Example: jag är en ful älg -> jagär en ful älg.

Image sample:
http://postimg.org/image/z3uhtvcwh/

This is a sample of svg code that renders wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="650px" height="650px" viewBox="0 0 650 650" enable-background="new 0 0 650 650" xml:space="preserve">
<text
transform="translate(197.08643,191.33691)"
id="text5"><tspan
x="-100"
y="0"
style="font-size:60px;fill:#000000;font-family:Arial">jag är jag är</tspan>
</text>
</svg>
```

Looking at the svg-image in an svg editor displays correct "jag är jag är".
I have tried different fonts...

I call imagemagick with: convert 1.svg 1.jpg

Imagemagick version:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.0-0 2012-10-11 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

I am very thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is acceptable for you to edit 1.svg try using UTF-8 encoded symbols:

```
jag &#228;r jag &#228;r
```

instead of

```
jag är jag är
```

tested with ImageMagick 6.6.0-1 2010-03-03 Q16, this is my output image:

[image]

Comment: I don't really want to do that, because it's user inputs. I guess I can write some php that will replace and use UTF-8 encoded symbols. I found out what was the problem. It was using the internal svg handler,  with my windows imagemagick installation. All answers here: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24611